# Debugging Custom SSIS Task

Tags: debugging, ssis, custom-controls

I'm trying to develop my first custom SSIS task.  I've got two instances of SSDT open -- one for building and debugging the task, and the other that uses the custom task.  Then in the first instance, I use the Attach to Process function from the Debug menu to debug the code.  That all works fine but my trouble is that each time I rebuild the task and register it in the GAC from the first instance, I have to close and reopen the second instance of SSDT.  If I don't, the second instance seems to still use the previous build of my custom task.  Is there some way besides closing/reopening Data Tools that will cause it to recognize the new build of the custom task?  All the closing/reopening is getting exhausting.

Answer (score 1):

While it has been a decade since I last built any custom components for SSIS, the work cycle is as you describe it.

The best bit of of advice I'd offer is to add post-build steps to your development process to GAC the DLL. Oh, and modify your Visual Studio shortcut to include `/nosplash` to eliminate the startup splash screen.

Comment: I already have the post-build step.  It's a nice time saver but the problem is with the other project that tries to use the DLL.  Doesn't seem to use the new version without the project being reloaded.  Or perhaps it can't load or run the new version for some reason so it defaults to the previous version?  I don't know.